# java.lang.illegalstatexception Application was not properly initialized

Tags: java, jsf, jboss

I am getting the following error when deploying an application on JBoss 4.2.1

```
   7:05:59,673 ERROR [Application Name]StandardWrapper.Throwable
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application was not properly initialized at 
   startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory
```

I browsed the net and I found many posts which suggested to add an entry in `web.xml` but that entry was already there. And all the required libraries are there in `web-inf`.

So any solutions anybody ?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your classpath is *clean* (i.e. no duplicate different versioned classes/JAR files, keep in mind that JBoss ships with builtin JSF libraries!) and that your `web.xml` is declared as *at least* Servlet 2.3.